# Varaiable entity extraction - No pattern in the entities of a sentence - NLP

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, azure-language-understanding

I'm working on a customer support bot which helps business users understand the meaning of certain technical terms or status of some of their requests. A typical sentence looks like below

1. Explain me about Air Compressor/Heating and cooling systems/ Law Of
   Thermodynamics
2. Get me the status of Ticket123/HEATER12

***What have I done so far***

I currently use Microsoft LUIS to identify the entities where I upload all the possible entities and LUIS does a string match and return them. The problem with this approach is

- The entity list keeps getting bigger and needs to be updated everyday
- User may type in spelling mistakes - In some cases, the word user types may not be a dictionary word for the spelling to be corrected.

***What's my solution (which doesn't seem to work well)***

I'm currently thinking of an approach to tag the POS and group the noun phrases/nouns but I dont think this will be an effective method.

Also one thing to be noted is that the entities don't follow any pattern. What should be my approach here. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the pointers helped you in anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve two distinct problems

1. Managing knowledge base for answering questions for users to learn/understand
2. providing the status of a particular ticket

The first part can be comprehensively managed by using Q&A maker service without employing a line of code. refer... https://www.qnamaker.ai/

The second part has a sole purpose of fetching a value from the database based on the entity value (ticket).

Focus on building and fine-tuning the bot only for the second part and integrate Q&A maker as a knowledge base which will take care of first part.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do below for your problems:

1. List all your entities in Excel, if it keeps getting bigger you just need to add more rows in excel and not on your code. After that write a regex to match your entities with the required information.
2. For spelling mistakes: You can implement something like `Fuzzywuzzy in Python`. You will get the nearest match and then you can apply the step 1 to capture your entity.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question, but I wanted to add that the modern solution would be to use Machine-Learned entities instead of List or Regex or Patterns. You just tag the entity in each utterance, and it will learn based on the context of the sentence. For example, if you trained LUIS based on the utterances in bullet one, it would start to recognize any phrase after "Explain me about...". It can be a bit hit or miss on single vs. multiple word phrases, but as you add more utterances with tagged entities, it will be better about giving you the expected results.

Modern solution for spelling mistakes would be to use Bing Search to pre-process your utterance before sending it to LUIS (on older versions of LUIS you could attach your spell checking directly to the LUIS recognizer creation, but in the latest version you have to do it separately).